# After adding a scope to an Azure AD B2C identity provider, how long does it take before the scope is include in the idp_access_token?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I keep running into this issue so am seeking an authoritative answer.

I have a Node.js web app in Azure with Azure AD B2C authentication enabled.

When I change a scope in:

`Azure AD B2C` > `Identity providers` > `[ select my IDP (an Azure AD tenant) ]`

[image]

It seems to take a long/arbitrary amount of time before the `idp_access_token` value that is returned after a successful sign in contains the newly added scope.

I find myself doing heaps of random things to try and force the change but nothing seems to work consistently - eg, logging out and back in again, re-starting the web app.

How long should this take and is there anyway to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the scenario in my environment.***

By default I have the following permissions granted

[image]

I have additionally given `User.ReadWrite.All ,Application.Read.All` ***Application permissions*** as profile delegated permission is not allowed

[image]

I configured OpenId provider following way with scopes openid profile

[image]

I had both idtoken and access token checked in authentication blade.

[image]

Then if I run the user flow, got the scopes as in IDP configuration
**With user 1**

[image]

---

**with user 2**

[image]

---

***Then I changed the scope and added Directory.Read.All***

> **Note :** Here UserId claim is given to map to ***`oid`***

[image]

***Also given `Directory.Read.All` permissions under API permissions blade of my app and granted admin consent to them.***

[image]

---

But the scopes while test run user flow  doesn’t seem to change during configuration.

[image]

---

***But when run , I could get the idp_access_token , with the scopes Directory.Read.All openid profile email as below.*** It doesn't take much time and returned as soon as its changed.Check if missed anything.

[image]

---

***Scopes in idp_access_token:***

[image]

---

**Reference :** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-get-started?tabs=app-reg-ga